# Escape whitespace characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
"hello\n\nsomeletters\t\nmoreletters\n"
```

What I want:

```
"hello\\n\\nsomeletters\\t\\nmoreletters\\n"
```

How to do it?

I know a `gsub` way. But it sounds very simple and seems to be a common problem therefore I am sure that Ruby Gods have already sent us a solution.

Comment: This problem is far less common than you imagine :) FWIW, I never needed to do this

Comment: @SergioTulentsev me neither.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to build a tsv. One of the fields is a text field. It could contain whitespace characters and blows up my tsv :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possibilities. The closest to what you want would be [`Regexp#escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
Regexp.escape "hello\n\nsomeletters\t\nmoreletters\n"
#⇒ "hello\\n\\nsomeletters\\t\\nmoreletters\\n"
```

But be aware it will escape some other symbols having a special meaning in regular expressions.

Also, we have [`Shellwords#escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-escape), which is probably not what you want here.

For escaping *backslashes only* there is no dedicated method because this operation basically has a little sense and it is not worth it to call it instead of:

```
"hello\n\nsomeletters\t\nmoreletters\n".gsub(
    /\n|\t/, {"\n" => "\\n", "\t" => "\\t"}
)
```

Please note, there are *no slash characters* in the initial string, hence you are to match all the expected sequences.

Comment: It depends on _why_ OP wants to escape the string, as he has not provided any hint.